# Linker symbols not found

Tags: c, macos, linker, libraries, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to compile something I've fetched off of github with `gcc`:

```
users-MBP:Chip-8-Emulator user$ gcc -o chip8 chip8.c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_Delay", referenced from:
      _chip8_draw in chip8-bc89fc.o
  "_SDL_Flip", referenced from:
      _chip8_draw in chip8-bc89fc.o
  "_SDL_GetKeyState", referenced from:
      _chip8_execute in chip8-bc89fc.o
      _chip8_prec in chip8-bc89fc.o
  "_SDL_GetVideoSurface", referenced from:
      _chip8_draw in chip8-bc89fc.o
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _chip8_prepare in chip8-bc89fc.o
  "_SDL_LockSurface", referenced from:
      _chip8_draw in chip8-bc89fc.o
  "_SDL_PollEvent", referenced from:
      _chip8_prepare in chip8-bc89fc.o
      _chip8_prec in chip8-bc89fc.o
  "_SDL_SetVideoMode", referenced from:
      _chip8_prepare in chip8-bc89fc.o
  "_SDL_UnlockSurface", referenced from:
      _chip8_draw in chip8-bc89fc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The error seems to be an issue with the `SDL` library in this case, but I've had the exact same issue with several other little projects I treid to compile. Before compiling, I installed the `SDL` libs and checked they are there:

```
users-MBP:Chip-8-Emulator user$ ls /usr/local/lib/
...           
libSDL-1.2.0.dylib       
libSDL.a                 
libSDL.dylib             
libSDLmain.a
...
```

After lots of Googling it seems I'm not the only one with this problem and I couldn't find solution that worked. It seems that `osx` doesn't include `/use/local/lib` in the default linker paths.

How can I fix this (a permanent solution would be welcome)?

**EDIT**
Following a suggestion from user Alex I tried with `$ gcc -o chip8 -L/usr/local/lib chip8.c`. The error and output is identical to the above.

Comment: You need to add `-lSDL` to your build command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add `-L/usr/local/lib -lSDL` to your GCC invocation.

As for a more permanent solution, this is a convention of OS X, and strictly speaking `/usr/local/lib` is a non-standard installation location.

Comment: I tried with `$ gcc -o chip8 -L/usr/local/lib chip8.c` and obtained the exact same output!

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to add the `-lSDL`

Comment: You should learn `Makefile`s or some other tool like `cmake`.